# awk usage in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk

actlist file contains around 15 records. I want to print/store each row in a variable to perform further action. script runs but echo $j displays blank value. What is the issue?
my script:

```
#/usr/bin/sh

acList=/root/john/actlist

Rowcount=`wc -l $acList | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`

for ((i=1; i<=Rowcount; i++)); do

j=`awk 'FNR == $i{print}' $acList`

echo $j
done
```

file: actlist

```
cat > actlist

5663233332 2223 2
5656556655 5545 5
4454222121 5555 5
.
.
.
```

Comment: You can use `Rowcount=$(wc -l < $aclist)` instead as if you supply the file to `wc` on its `stdin` like that, it doesn't tell you the filename (since it doesn't know it) and then you don't need `awk` to remove the filename.

Comment: The issue is you are using shell to manipulate text instead of the UNIX text-manipulation tool, awk. shell is an environment from which to call tools, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens to be related to quotes and to the way the shell interpolates variables.

More specifically, when you write

```
j=`awk "FNR == $i{print}" $acList`
```

the AWK code must be enclosed into **double quotes**.  This is necessary if you want the shell to be able to substitute the `$i` with the actual value stored in the `i` variable.

On the other hand, if you write

```
j=`awk 'FNR == $i{print}' $acList`
```

i.e. with **single quotes**, the `$i` will be interpreted as a literal string.

Hence the fixed code will read:

```
#/usr/bin/sh

acList=/root/john/actlist

Rowcount=`wc -l $acList | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`

for ((i=1; i<=Rowcount; i++)); do

    j=`awk "FNR == $i{print}" $acList`

    echo $j
done
```

**Remember**: it is always the shell that does variable interpolation before calling other commands.

Having said that, there are some places, in supplied code, where some improvements could be devised.  But that's another story.

Comment: There are MANY issues with the above, including: Don't use ticks to call shell tools, always quote shell variables, don't use undirected wc and then strip out the file name, don't use double quotes around awk scripts, do pass shell variable values to awk using -v, don't use shell to manipulate text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would probably be better off with this for parsing your file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a b c; do
   echo $a, $b, $c
done < "$actlist"
```

**Output:**

```
5663233332, 2223, 2
5656556655, 5545, 5
4454222121, 5555, 5
```

**Updated**

Whilst the above demonstrates the concept I was suggesting, as @EdMorton rightly says in the comments section, the following code would be more robust for a production environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r a b c; do
   echo "$a, $b, $c"
done < "$actlist"
```

Comment: WHile it'd be OK for exactly the posted input, that would fail in interesting ways if the input file contained globbing chars, backslashes, etc. or if its name contained white space (and other chars?). You'd need to write it as `while IFS= read -r a b c; do echo "$a, $b, $c"; done < "$actlist"` to be reasonably robust.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately all your script does is print the contents of the input file so we can't help you figure out the right approach to do whatever it is you REALLY want to do without more information on what that is but chances are this is the right starting point:

```
acList=/root/john/actlist
awk '
{ print }
' "$acList"
```